# Regex to Catch Url

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, http, regex-group

I have an url: `http://200.73.81.212/.CREDIT-UNION/update.php` None of reg expressions I've found and develop myself works. I'm working on phishing mails dataset and there are lots of strange hyperlinks. This is one of mine:
`https?:\/\/([a-zA-z0-9]+.)+)|(www.[a-zA-Z0-9]+.([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)(((/[\.A-Za-z0-9]+))+/?`.
Of course no success. I work in Python.
EDIT:
I need a regex to catch this kind of url's and, also, any ordinary hyperlinks, like:
`https://cnn.com/`
`www.foxnews.com/story/122345678`
 Any thoughts?

Comment: Regex requires a regular pattern; we need a conclusive list of URLs to match against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
import re

phish = re.compile('''(?P<http>http\://)
                        (?P<ipaddress>(([0-9]*(\.)?)[0-9]*)*)/\.
                        (?P<name>(\.)?([A-Za-z]*)(\-)?([A-Za-z]*))/
                        (?P<ending>(update\.php))''', re.VERBOSE)

example_string = 'http://200.73.81.212/.CREDIT-UNION/update.php'

found_matches = []
# check that matches actually exist in input string
if phish.search(example_string):
    # in case there are many matches, iterate over them
    for mtch in phish.finditer(example_string):
        # and append matches to master list
        found_matches.append(mtch.group(0))

print(found_matches)
# ['http://200.73.81.212/.CREDIT-UNION/update.php']
```

This is flexible enough so now in case you have alternate endings than update.php, you can simply include them in the named capture group  by separating all alternate ending matches with |, i.e.

```
(update\.php|remove\.php, ...)
```

Furthermore, your ip address named capture group can take any number of 123.23.123.12, it doesnt have to be a fixed number of repeating numbers followed by period patterns. Now I believe IP addresses cap out at 3 numbers, so you could anchor those down to make sure you are matching the right types of numbers with curly brackets:

```
[0-9]{2, 3}\. # minimum of 2 numbers, maximum of 3
```

Comment: @Tom it honestly takes a lot of trial and error. This book helped me tremendously in getting really good with regex's in Python: https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1534725588&sr=8-4&keywords=python+regex

Answer (score 0):

While @datawrestler answer works for original question, I had to extend it to catch wider group of url's (I've edited the question). This url, seems to work, for the task:
`r"""(https?://www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(/[a-zA-Z0-9.@-]+){0,20})|\`
`(https?://[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(/[a-zA-Z0-9.@-]+){0,20})|\`
`(www.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(/[a-zA-Z0-9.@-]+){0,20})"""`
Three alternatives: `https?://www`, `https://domain`, `www.domain`